# Question about CoCreateInstance() method's implementation

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a question about how CoCreateInstnace() method locate and create an instance of a CoClass contained in a COM DLL.

Accroding to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615(VS.85).aspx):

> The CoCreateInstance function provides
>   a convenient shortcut by connecting to
>   the class object associated with the
>   specified CLSID, creating an
>   uninitialized instance, and releasing
>   the class object. As such, it
>   encapsulates the following
>   functionality:

```
CoGetClassObject(rclsid, dwClsContext, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, &pCF); 
hresult = pCF->CreateInstance(pUnkOuter, riid, ppvObj) 
pCF->Release();
```

So I am wondering if this is **exactly** how CoCreateInstnace is implemented? Or is it just a **logic equivalent**? If its real implementation is not like this, I am totally confused about how CoCreateInstnace could find and make an instance of the proper CoClass with merely a CLSID and some DLL location information registered in the Windows registry.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It does a lot more, but that takes a book.  *Exactly* what part looks like black magic to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it by debugging with debug version of MSVCRT libraries within the Visual Studio IDE. Alternatively, you can scan the VC++ include header files